# How to show a child table attached to row group ligne in DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatable, datatables

I need to have rowGroup rows and show the child table by clicking on a button.
For that, I want to :

- Hide all the rows from the parent table
- Get all the child rows data in a single table per rowGroup row

I Have tried to hide the rows to add a CSS via

```
"createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) {
//$('td', row).eq(3).css("display", "none");
$('td', row).css("display", "none");
$('td', row).eq(0).css("display", "");
},
```

Here is a test case : http://live.datatables.net/komubuce/91/edit
Here only the rows at the position 0 were shown because I new to show the second table.
But is there a way to hide all the rows (when I mean to hide it's for display: none ) and have the child table instead of the rows of the parent's table.

Here's what I have :

1. - RowGroup row
2. - (parent row to hide)
3. child table

And you can see below, what I want :

1. - RowGroup row
2. child table (with all the data - shown if the '+' button was clicked in the first row)

[image: what I want]
[image]

Do you know a way to hide all the rows on the init of the table and to show the child table instead of showing the rows?

Thanks in advance